# WiFi connects to Hotspot but unable to connect to some other wifi

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, broadcom

I've recently purchased a `AC1300 Wireless Dual Band PCI Express Adapter(Archer T6E)`. It uses a Broadcom chip (BCM4360 802.11ac).

I have a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 and installed the driver from `Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers (bcmwl-kernel-source)`.

In my `Settings -> Wi-Fi` I see SSIDs of my 2.4Ghz networks (although I have a 5GHz network and I can't see it).

My 2.4GHz network uses `WPA2`. When I enter the password for the network, it tries to connect to it, but after a minute it fails and ask for the password again.

Then I created a Hotspot using my iPhone, and the system connects to it in seconds.

I'm sure the password is correct, I've reset my router, changed its password, and also tried to connect to another router with the same security config.

I even shared my Ethernet connection from my MacBook through wifi (with no password), but it wasn't able to connect to it either.

So far the only wireless network that I've been able to connect to is iPhone's hotspot.

```
sudo lshw -c network

  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 03
       serial: 50:3e:aa:71:a4:81
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=172.20.10.13 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:a4400000-a4407fff memory:a4200000-a43fffff
```

```
lspci

04:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

```
rfkill list all

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
sudo iwlist wlp4s0 scan

          Cell 01 - Address: E6:9A:DC:7D:4E:12
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-33 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"My's iPhone"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 96ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000E4D616864692773206950686F6E65
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 200100
                    IE: Unknown: 23021100
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A2D0017FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 7F080400000000000040
                    IE: Unknown: DD0A0017F206010103010000
                    IE: Unknown: DD0D0017F206020106E49ADC7D4E13
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180201001C0000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 02 - Address: 6C:AD:EF:05:63:04
                    Channel:5
                    Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
                    Quality=64/70  Signal level=-46 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"3M-WiFi-connection"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 96ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0012334D2D736C6F772D636F6E6E656374696F6E
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030105
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 0706555320010B14
                    IE: Unknown: 33082001020304050607
                    IE: Unknown: 33082105060708090A0B
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0106
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AEE1117FFFF0000010000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1605000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 4A0E14000A002C01C800140005001900
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 0B05010015127A
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4307000000
```

I also ran `dmesg -w` and switched from `hotspot` to `router`. When theconnection fails and it asks for a password again, if I cancel it I'll see a `IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready`, and then when it reconnects to `hotspot` I see `IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp4s0: link becomes ready`.

I also tried to disable IPv6 all together from `/etc/sysctl.conf`, but it didn't change anything.

P.S: After reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers), I ended up installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` and also `firmware-b43-installer` non of them fixed my problem.

Because the system works fine with Hotspot, I'm assuming that this is less than a driver issue and more of a configuration issue!

Comment: I think you should check the allowed 5GHz channels in your router against what is allowed in the United States and set your router to a 5 GHz channel that matches

Comment: @Jeremy31 I fixed the regulatory configuration. Now the 5GHz network is visible, but it won't connect.

Comment: For anyone with the same issue about the 5GHz band, I used `iw reg set US` to set my regulatory region to US. Also I sat channel 48 in my router config.

Comment: @Fabby I've edited the question and explained why it's not a duplicate. If you still think it's a duplicate let me know what I'm missing here.

Comment: **Close vote retracted...**